# Kivy - Search bar function

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, uisearchbar, kivymd

I want to see if someone can suggest or point me to a right direction. I want to have a search bar in the app where it searches a table with two columns and suggest the most closes one. Is there any function call Search bar for kivy. If not then how can i achieve this.